# Is it possible to remove that ugly black background around PNGs with opacity < 1 in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, png, opacity, alpha

Here's my site:
http://rps.sanscode.com

Load it up in IE7 or 8 and you can see the ugly rings I am talking about.

Does anyone have a solution to get rid of them? or perhaps some advice on how to change the images to remove them?

I am using jQuery if that helps.

Comment: `$('img[src$=".png"].removeUglyRings()` :)

Comment: omg i wish.... ps syntax error, -1 :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AlphaImageLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on pngs to help with this, just like on gifs. I've seen that in a few Colorbox themes.

Note that forces some compromises on CSS - you can't use background positioning on these images, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the code from here: http://youngpup.net/projects/sleight (demo page here: http://youngpup.net/projects/sleight/demo.html) to do this on my site http://entrian.com/source-search/